# On non-factoriality of a class of simple hypersurface singularities

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$.

> For which values of $n\ge 4$ the local ring
> $$R_n=k[[x,y,z,w]]/(x^2y+y^{n-1}+z^2+w^2)$$
> is not a UFD ?

I know that any such ring is an integral domain in general, but I don't know any proof of non factoriality.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to show $R$ is an integral domain, but it is not a UFD.

For instance, $P = (y, z+iw)R$ is a height one prime ideal, and it is not principal (use Nakayama's lemma to check this).

Comment: @Youngsu: thanks for the amazing answer. And to see why it is a domain, notice that the ring is a simple hypersurface singularity of dimension $3$ (for a reference, see Chapter 9, Theorem 9.8 of Cohen-Macaulay Representation Theory, by Leuschke and Wiegand) ... it is known that simple hypersurface singularities of dimension at least $3$ are integral domain (exercise 9.30 of same book) ...